# Determine content-length using urllib2

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm making a request via urllib2 that is coming back with the following headers:

```
>>> dict(response.info())
{'expires': 'Wed, 31 Dec 1969 19:00:00 EST, Wed, 31 Dec 1969 19:00:00 EST', 'server': 'Apache-Coyote/1.1, Apache-Coyote/1.1', 'connection': 'close', 'pragma': 'No-cache, No-cache', 'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-cache', 'date': 'Thu, 19 Jan 2012 20:16:00 GMT', 'content-type': 'audio/mpeg'}
```

As I understand it, since 'connection: close' is set, the request will keep streaming back until the remote host finishes, so no Content-Length  is set.  It seems like I should be able to determine the length of the content by somehow analyzing the response object, but I can't figure out how to do it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you would need to call `read()` on the response to read it into a string, and then call `len()` on the string.

```
data = response.read()
length = len(data)
```

Comment: I assumed that would give me the length of the entire request (including headers) and I thought Content-Length only included the body.  Is that incorrect?

Comment: According to the docs at http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPResponse.read, `read()` reads the response body.

Comment: Yup, I've just tried it; `read()` only returns the response body, so you can use it to find the Content-Length.